# Google Chrome address bar searches instead of going to URL

Tags: google-chrome

Using Google Chrome (16.0.912.41 beta specifically), when I modify the parameters to the URL in the address bar, Chrome sometimes performs a Google search for the string instead of going to the URL the string represents.

For example, I use Trac on an internal network and access it through Chrome. If I'm on a track ticket at this URL: http://trac/project/ticket/1287 (the URL strips off the http and all that is visible in the URL is trac/project/ticket/1287)  If I want to quickly go to a different ticket, I just change the 1287 to the ID of the new ticket.  I change the 1287 to  1288 and press enter and Chrome takes me here: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=trac%2Fproject%2Fticket%2F1288 instead of going to http:// trac/project/ticket/1288, which is what I intended.

How can I tell Chrome that when the address bar contains the string "trac/project/ticket", go to that URL and do not perform a search?

Comment: First thing I would do is install the current version of Chrome.  Version 16 was released yesterday.  The second issue is you need to setup your internal network to not strip the http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that your base domain (trac) doesn't look like a website domain.  My guess is that you are on some internal network.  I would try using the fully qualified domain (i.e. trac.yourinternaldomain.com/project/ticket/1288).

Comment: This answer fixes my issue of Chrome sometimes thinking my string is a URL and other times a search term. Thanks!