# Google Chrome Searches instead of Following the Address

Tags: google-chrome

If I type in a URL (e.g., https://somedomain.com/some/url/) Google Chrome sometimes tries to search Google instead of resolving to the page.  The suggestion menu sees the url and contains *Google Encrypted Search Provider Search* beside it.

It isn't consistent when this is done.  If I slightly modify the path by adding "foo/"  or removing "url/", it will follow to the underlying webpage.  Even if I add a hash "#foo" to the end, it'll follow the address, but not if I only include the hash '#' without extra characters.

I figured this has something to do with the browsing history, so I opened the History, searched for the path, and deleted all instances where it tried to go to google.com to perform the search; which didn't work.

[Google Chrome address bar searches instead of going to URL](https://superuser.com/questions/367373/google-chrome-address-bar-searches-instead-of-going-to-url) is a similar, but the answer did not apply.  The issue is not related to the domain.

Comment: Try this : In Chrome, click the three-dots icon, click on Settings, and under "Search engine" ensure that "Google" is chosen.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your comment, yes it was selected.  Chrome was a relatively new install, without many add-ons (none that affected the URL), but I hoped to describe that it seems more to do with a history, since the minor differences in the URL worked as expected.  At some point the URL may have failed and so Google may have needed to perform a search and thus is doing it every time since for that particular endpoint

Comment: If you suspect that this is the case, you could [Clear your Chrome browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), instead of deleting selectively.

Comment: It's a suspicion, not an assertion that it would work; however, the history is necessary. I suppose I could setup a test machine to test this in future where history isn't as vital

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to avoid Google from searching:

1. Enter URL in the address bar

   - Do not hit enter if the suggestion is for the encrypted search
2. Click into the body of the browser so that the suggestion menu goes away
3. Click back on the address bar

   - The suggestion menu should not appear
4. Hit Enter/Return via keyboard

This should then store the URL in the browser's suggestion history.  Next time the URL is entered it will go to it, instead of searching for it on Google.com (or whatever the default search engine is).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very well known bug of Chromium (and, as of today, I can reproduce it on the latest stable Google Chrome version on my machine as well).
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362356

Scroll to the end of the page and read two latest comments. I'll quote them here too just for fun and for the sake of history:

> Comment 20 by schwa...@gmail.com on Mon, Apr 4, 2022, 4:03 PM GMT+3
> this "feature" still exists.
> i'm working with local vagrant vm which has a domain "app.local" assigned, my windows host file also has app.local resolved to its IP address.
> On boot vagrant opens http://app.local/ in browser, which works finde.
> but then in click into the addrerss bar and just add "info.php" after already present URL, which results in "app.local/info.php" since chrome is hiding the protocol, but when i hit enter instead of requesting the info.php file, chrome makes google search for "app.local/info.php", which is the stupidest thing in the history of the entire universe and clearly a bug.

> Comment 21 by ryang...@gmail.com on Wed, Apr 19, 2023, 6:43 AM GMT+3
> 9 years on and Google is still pulling this desperate to show you search results routine?  I forgot about the / trick because my preferred browser doesn't need it to work correctly.

For a very uncomfortable workaround one can use a resolved IP-address instead of host/domain name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: my answer should be posted as a comment actually, but I can't comment due to low reputation of mine. yes, you are correct it is of no help. what i meant to state is there is actually no proper solution due to this "feature" being actually a bug of the browser.